# Redirect a asp page to php page using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a completely rebuild my website using php. The old website was made by somebody else who build it in asp. I have a lot pages that need redirecting to the new pages. I know I will need to do this for every individual page however I'm not sure how to do this.
I have for example:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/productdetails/617/6/Casio%20CDP120%20Digital%20Piano%20in%20Black/
```

needs redirecting to

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302
```

Any help welcome

Comment: Are ASP and PHP files hosted in same web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule "^productdetails/617/6/Casio CDP120 Digital Piano in Black/?$" /Casio-CDP120-Digital-Piano-in-Black/302 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks again. Working perfect.

Comment: It's funny that yours always work perfectly and that so far, mine rarely work! :) +1

Comment: Thanks @zx81, you answers on `mod_rewrite` are also getting better gradually, but these are some special cases like handling spaces etc. btw your regex answers are already hitting target.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I plan to go through the first couple pages of your top-voted mod-rewrite answers to see what more I can learn. I've already made a huge amount of notes and a good debug setup. But experience is everything.  :)

Comment: Sure, feel free to ask for any clarification or explanation. My very old answers many not be that good I think.